# `Program Fixpoint` with mutual recursion with dependent type in Coq

Tags: coq

In my project, I try to push more proofs to function definitions, which unavoidably adds lots of dependent types into the function definitions, and the result is I am using `Program Fixpoint` and define the body using proof mode.

```
  Require Import Program.

  Variable P : nat -> Prop.

  Program Fixpoint a (n : nat) : sigT P := _
  with b (n : nat) : sigT P := _.
  Next Obligation.
```

However, in the case of mutual recursion as above, after entering proof mode, `a` and `b` are no longer visible to each other.

```
1 subgoal (ID 183)

  P : nat -> Prop
  n : nat
  ============================
  {x : nat & P x}
```

Is there a way to define such thing taking advantage from both `Program` and proof mode?